# Dynamic Immutable Map updating

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am working with Immutable and I found that there is a lot of problems when you want to update multiple keys in an immutable data unit.

Now I am doing this actions to achieve an updated object.

```
state.setIn(["user", "email"], action.payload.user.email)
            .setIn(["user", "pass"], action.payload.user.password)
            .setIn(["user", "pending"], action.meta.pending)
            .setIn(["user", "username"], action.payload.user.name)
            .setIn(["user", "charity"], action.payload.user.charityOrganizationId)
            .setIn(["user", "avatar"], action.payload.user.avatarElementIds)
            .setIn(["user", "isAuthorized"], action.payload.user.isAuthorized);
```

it's looking not so beauty and I want to create a method that will allow me to handle it like that:

```
dynamicUpdate(immutableData, newDataCollection) {
  var res;
  for (var key in newDataCollection) {
   res = immutableData.setIn(["user", key], newDataCollection[key])
  }
  return res;
}

   var newState =  dynamicUpdate(ImmutableState, {
      email : "newEmail",
      pass : "newPass"
    })
```

is it possible? Or there is some other way exists to do that?

and I think it can cause a big memory issues because there is a new Immutable Map will be create on every setIn.  I read about withMutations, but I don't understand how it can be used.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just do `state.mergeDeep(fromJS(action.payload.user))`. You have control over the user key of the payload object so make all the keys match and let the `mergeDeep` handle it for you.

Comment: There might be some other solutions, but I found that this works fairly well for these types of use cases and it a lot easier to read/type/understand.

Comment: Thank you so much VanDanic!